# Accessing a MySQL database through SSH tunnels

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 servers: `serverA`, `serverB` and `serverMySQL`.

`serverMySQL` is lying behind a firewall and cannot be accessed by `serverB`.

`serverA` can access both `serverB` and `serverMySQL` via SSH.

Is there any way I can setup a SSH tunnel so that I am able to access the MySQL database located at `serverMySQL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If serverB can access the MySQL server (port 3306 not SSH) you have to run in serverA:

```
ssh -L 3306:mysqlServer:3306 serverB
```

In serverA then configure MySQL server as 127.0.0.1:3306

If serverB only can access MySQL with SSH then you have to run in serverA:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:12345 serverB
```

and then in serverB:

```
ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 serverMySQL
```

The 12345 is just any port that is not used (and over 1024)

Comment: Using `autossh` might be a better approach, since it attempts to keep the connection alive.

Comment: The comment by @jotik is good, but it builds on what I have told. After you have it working add key authentication (so that you don't have to enter passwords all the time) and then add autossh.